# Netbeans, jsp:include

Tags: jsf, netbeans, include

I'm using JSF in NetBeans. All I want to do is to include a page within another page. But whatever I tried, and when I run the main page, I get no error but I can't see my included page in a main page. Why?

My main page is:

```
<jsp:root version="2.1" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
    xmlns:webuijsf="http://www.sun.com/webui/webuijsf">

<jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"/>
<f:view>
    <webuijsf:page id="page1">
        <webuijsf:html id="html1">
            <webuijsf:head id="head1">
                <webuijsf:link id="link1" url="/css/front.css"/>
                <webuijsf:script id="script1" url="/scripts/front2.js"/>
                <webuijsf:link url="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"/>
            </webuijsf:head>
            <webuijsf:body id="body1" style="-rave-layout: grid">
                <webuijsf:form id="form1">

                        <!-- This is where I include my page -->
                        <f:subview id="nav">
                        <jsp:include page="frontsitemenu.jsp" />
                        </f:subview>


              </webuijsf:form>
            </webuijsf:body>
        </webuijsf:html>
    </webuijsf:page>
</f:view>
```

My included page is:

```
<f:subview id="frontsitemenu">
    <f:verbatim>
        <p>rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr</p>
    </f:verbatim>
</f:subview>
```

Can someone please help me? Thanks

Comment: I would check the placement of the frontsitemenu.jsp file.  Maybe it isn't in the directory you think it is and you'll have to include the path from the web application root to that file.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use:

```
<%@include file="_frontsitemenu.jsp" %>
```

Thats whats working for me

Answer (score 0):

You should have ony **one** `f:subview` per include. Now you've two, a `<f:subview id="nav">` which wraps the `jsp:include` and a `<f:subview id="frontsitemenu">` inside the include page itself. The normal practice is that they're placed in the include file **only**. So, remove the `<f:subview id="nav">` from the parent page.